# dynamically set default option of choice field based on regex in django

Tags: regex, django, django-forms

I need to set the default value of the field 'procedure_field' dynamically based on input 'procedure'
eg: procedure_field is populated with a123,b123,c123 etc
    if procedure is c then i need to set default value as c123. 
How to do it??

```
views.py

tickets = request.POST['tickets']
tickets = str(tickets).translate(None,'[]\'')
procedure = request.POST['procedure']
form = forms.fillForm(initial{'ticket_field':tickets,---code to set default----})
return render(request, 'fill_tickets.html',{'form':form})

forms.py

class fillForm(forms.Form):
ticket_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,required=True)
procedure_field = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=get_procedures(),required=True )
```

get_procedures() returns static values..
when the form is loaded in html,i need to dynamically set default value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you want to have a default (correct) value for procedure that replaces the supplied procedure value in case of it being invalid.

This is a great opportunity to use a [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) (-ish) operator:

```
procedure = procedure if re.compile("[a-zA-Z][\\d]+", re.IGNORECASE).match(procedure) else "a123"
```

This is officially called [Conditional Expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/).

Which looks like this unfolded:

```
import re

regex = re.compile("[a-zA-Z][\\d]+", re.IGNORECASE)
if not regex.match(procedure):
    procedure = "c123"
```